# Android WorkManager retrieve all requests

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I using WorkManager instead of AlarmManager and i want to update a request at runtime so i need to retrieve that request. How can i do that?

```
OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TripWorker.class)
                           .setInputData(dataBuilder.build())
                           .setInitialDelay(milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                           .addTag("Tag")
                           .build();

workManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify an existing WorkRequest.

You can use WorkManager's [unique work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work) and enqueue a modified WorkRequest to replace the existing one:

1. Use [`enqueueUniqueWork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniqueWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)) instead of using `enqueue`
2. When you need to modify the WorkRequest, create a new one and enqueue it with `UniqueWorkRequest`, using the same unique name, with a [`REPLACE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#REPLACE) policy.

Keep in mind that the your Worker maybe running while you replace it. You need to carefully handle stoppages in your Worker (stoppages are cooperative, so you need to add some code as explained in the [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work#stopping)) using the [`isStopped`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#isStopped()) method and implementing the [`onStopped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#onStopped()) callback.

Comment: thanx bro it work now, but i wonder why i can't retrieve the request and edited it what is behind that prevent?

Comment: Main problem is that your WorkRequest maybe already registered to JobScheduler, this would actually require to delete the previous Job and register a new one with all the corner cases correctly handled, usually something that depends on the particular work you scheduled...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getWorkInfoByIdLiveData` or `getWorkInfoByTagLiveData`. WorkManager adds an implicit tag to every enqueue() which is the simple name of the class. So you can do something like:

```java
workManager.getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(TripWorker.class.getName())
```

Comment: I tray to use this line before post this question! it return `LiveData<List<WorkInfo>>`! it contain `WorkInfo` object and that not a `WorkRequest` object

Comment: Hi @Rahul, this is not related to this question. 
I have another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74514057/how-to-fix-crash-illegalstateexception-the-file-system-on-the-device-is-in-a-ba

I want to know when ForceStoppableRunnable class is used. The description at the top of the class is not very clear. Please help me understand.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible as of v2.7.1 to get the `WorkRequest` that was submitted.

---

For people that want to view input data that was passed to a work request:

What you *can* do is to save the input data of the work request on your own, e.g. in a Room table (if you use room) or anywhere else and use the ID that is returned from WorkManager.enqueue as key.

Then, by getting the list of workInfos you can query your database table (or other storage) by their IDs.